# Expression Blend3

Tags: expression-blend, expression-blend-3

I am new in Expression Blend3.  Now I got a game created in it and asked me to edit the interface.  I successfully changed the font and colour.  But somethings are inserted as "Path" as it's showing in Properties.  I want to replace the current ones with new one.  Can I make a file in PSD (or png, jpeg etc) and replace it with current path image?  How it can be possible?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit a Path by selecting that Path in the layers tab and editing the properties in the properties tab.

As for Photoshop, there's Import from Photoshop and Import from Illustrator in Blend 3, these is a really neat update for Blend 3 as it manages the layers from a PSD so that you have your layers within Blend.

Hope that helps!